# running n Processes in parallel using same data - in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, mutex, race-condition

I need help running n process in parallel using the same data.
the run() function using check() inside an infinite loop.

using process.start() and join() runs only one process and using Pool(), the processes got stuck

The structure of the program in the code below

```
class App:
    items = dict()


def check(item):
    # checking the item and updates its data
    return item


def run(app):
    while True:
        check(app.items['item_id'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    container = dict()

    app = App()

    # create here - n processes (running in parallel) of run(app)
```

I would appreciate any help or direction that would help solve the problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show the program where _using process.start() and join() runs only one process_.

Comment: Check out `concurrent.futures`. If you show your work and demonstrate that you are also attempting to solve this problem then others will help.